# Boolean returning false after it was just set to true

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I have a login and have this Display Popup showing more then once so my logic was

Create a bool and check if its true/False then display the popup

So user logins correctly It navigates to main page and

```
 MainPage.justloggedin = false;
```

On the Mainpage

```
 public static bool justloggedin { get; set; } = true;
```

```
 if (justloggedin != true)
 {
    DisplayAlert("Logged in", "Login Process Complete. Welcome", "OK");
    justloggedin = true;
 }
```

It shows once then if you go to another page and go back it displays again then never displays again after the 2nd display.

I cant understand this....

Login:

```
private void Login_Phase2()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var user in list)
                {

                    if (user.username == Usernamelabel.Text)
                    {
                        if (Usernamelabel.Text = "TesterDetail")
//This is just for one single Testing account They cant see prices
                        {
                            GlobalVariable.Tester = true;
                            Preferences.Set("CId", user.id.ToString());
                            if (WpApiCredentials.token != null) 
                            Preferences.Set("Token", 
                            WpApiCredentials.token);

                            Application.Current.MainPage = new Home();
                            MainPage.justloggedin = false;

                            Preferences.Set("CUsername", user.username);
                            Preferences.Set("CEmail", user.email);
                            LoggedIn = true;
                            Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            GlobalVariable.Tester = false;
                            Preferences.Set("CId", user.id.ToString());
                            if (WpApiCredentials.token != null) 
                            Preferences.Set("Token", 
                            WpApiCredentials.token);
                            Application.Current.MainPage = new Home();
                            MainPage.justloggedin = false;

                            Preferences.Set("CUsername", user.username);
                            Preferences.Set("CEmail", user.email);
                            LoggedIn = true;
                            Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }
```

The part above is not so much a login as just retrieving the correct customer to get the details from them Email, ID ect
The Secure login is Process 1

Note: If you want to recommend a better way about exposing the Customer So I can get there details Please do

I had issue's with LinQ also doubleing some variables so Went back to the Awkward Foreach

Comment: The problem is probably in a part of your code which you haven't put in your question. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: I  think, the member variables set to default value, when it is navigated back from another page.

Comment: Included the whole login for you, I'm not using this anywhere els. I can't see anything els having a impact on this

Comment: @Noorul Default value is true so then it shouldn't display it as I'm checking ```if(var != true) ```

Comment: Also keep in mind that it's static, so any new MainPage instance will reset it to "true", since (according to docs): "Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created"

Comment: @tobypls Indeed but i want it to be true so it doesn't display on every new instance? the issue is its showing twice which means its false on the first new instance after it is set

Comment: @tobypls It is a static property, so the (static) initializer runs just once. Not on every instance creation.

Comment: Are you sure about the order (and count) of invocation of that "if" (that resets your property to true) and your Login_Phase2 (that *may* set it to false)? Can you put a breakpoint in both and check?

Comment: How many users are there in the list that you use in `Login_Phase2()`? The code in the loop looks broken if there is more than one user. For example, whether `GlobalVariable.Tester` ends up as true can depend on the order of the users - if if there's one test user and one non-test user and the test user is last, it will end up true whereas if a non-test user is last it will end up false.

Comment: The best practice to initialize the static property in the constructor. You can initialize in the constructor and try that.

Comment: What you need is a static variable in `App` class and not `MainPage` class for your use case.

Comment: @MatthewWatson So theres 150+ "Customers" I'm trying to expose that individual to get there details, Its actually ```if(Usernamelabel.Text == "Testers Details")``` was a little embarrassed to put that there

Answer (score 0):

I got around this.

Going to share what I did But I'm still looking for a answer as to why this is happening.

In

```
LoginPhase2(){
 foreach (var user in list)
                {

                    if (user.username == Usernamelabel.Text)
                    {
                        if (Usernamelabel.Text == "TesteDetails")
                        {
                            GlobalVariable.Tester = true;
                            Preferences.Set("CId", user.id.ToString());
                            if (WpApiCredentials.token != null) Preferences.Set("Token", WpApiCredentials.token);

                            App.justloggedin = false;
                            Preferences.Set("CUsername", user.username);
                            Preferences.Set("CEmail", user.email);

                            Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            GlobalVariable.Tester = false;
                            Preferences.Set("CId", user.id.ToString());
                            if (WpApiCredentials.token != null) Preferences.Set("Token", WpApiCredentials.token);
                            Application.Current.MainPage = new Home();
                            App.justloggedin = false;
                            Preferences.Set("CUsername", user.username);
                            Preferences.Set("CEmail", user.email);

                            Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                        }

                    }

                }
                if (App.justloggedin != true)
                {
                    App.justloggedin = true;
                    DisplayAlert("Logged in", "Login Process Complete. Welcome to Mica Market", "OK");
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new Home();
                }
}
```